# Does Chrome mobile have some feature to reduce CSS animations when low on battery?

Tags: css, ios, google-chrome, mobile

I introduced some fade-in/fade-out logic when I'm transitioning between "screens" in my react web application. You can see an example of the "screen transition" here: [Rabbit](https://rabbit.netlify.com/anon1) ([source code](https://bitbucket.org/kopi-cloud/rabbit/src/c4ba0ace5ac8a1327251190ca8e3e9e7a1141e71/frontend/src/Navigation/NavigationProvider.tsx#lines-76)).

The animations were working fine on my phone in Safari, but not Chrome.
At first, I thought it was something to do with Chrome on iOS, but today it seems to be working fine.

I've realised that when I was first trying this yesterday, my phone was quite low on battery (no warning, by maybe about 30% ish).  Today with my phone fully charged, the "screen transition" animation in Chrome is working fine.

I tried to reproduce by going into iOS accessibility settings and setting "reduced motion", but that doesn't reproduce the issue.  My app detects that `prefers-reduced-motion` is set to `reduced`, but the screen transition animations seem to function fine regardless of that (though perhaps in future I should turn off the animations if the media-query returns true).

So, while I sit here waiting for my phone to discharge - can anyone point me to any documentation about Chrome not performing animations if the device is low on battery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone finding this from a search: I was not able to find anything about a "low battery" mode relating to animations on iOS.

The cause of my disappearing animations in Chrome seems to be some kind of intermittent bug.  I've seen it a few times since (never managed to reproduce reliably though) and restarting the browser seems to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, the [Battery API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getBattery) is available on Chrome, and you can retrieve information such as the charging status or remaining battery level.